# Displaying uicollectinviewcellls using subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm a trying to display cells at defined points (as stored in core data) by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout. This code displays the cell in the defined point when i add an object and i am already viewing the collectionview, however the objects don't appear when the collection view is loaded or refreshed. I have connected by custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout to self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout but the only time i reference it is in the cellforitematindexpath when i pass it the object which contains it's co-ordinates. What have i missed?

```
#import "DayViewLayout.h"

@interface DayViewLayout () {
    NSMutableArray *_insertedIndexPaths;
    NSMutableArray *_deletedIndexPaths;
}

@end

@implementation DayViewLayout


- (void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];
    _insertedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    _deletedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (void)prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:(NSArray*)updates
{
    [super prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:updates];
    for (UICollectionViewUpdateItem *updateItem in updates) {
        if (updateItem.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateActionInsert) {
            [_insertedIndexPaths addObject:updateItem.indexPathAfterUpdate];
        }
        else if (updateItem.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateActionDelete) {
            [_deletedIndexPaths addObject:updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate];
        }
    }
}


- (void)finalizeCollectionViewUpdates
{
    [_insertedIndexPaths removeAllObjects];
    [_deletedIndexPaths removeAllObjects];
}


- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)itemIndexPath
{
    if ([_insertedIndexPaths containsObject:itemIndexPath]) {

        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes =
        [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
         layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:itemIndexPath];


        CGRect visibleRect =
        (CGRect){.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset,
            .size = self.collectionView.bounds.size};
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect),
                                        CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
        attributes.alpha = 0.0f;
        attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.6f,
                                                        0.6f,
                                                        1.0f);


        return attributes;
    } else {
        return [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
    }
}


- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)itemIndexPath
{
    if ([_deletedIndexPaths containsObject:itemIndexPath]) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes =
        [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
         layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

        CGRect visibleRect =
        (CGRect){.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset,
            .size = self.collectionView.bounds.size};
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect),
                                        CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
        attributes.alpha = 0.0f;
        attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.3f,
                                                        1.3f,
                                                        1.0f);

        return attributes;
    } else {
        return [super finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
    }
}

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes =
    [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self applySettingsToAttributes:attributes];
    return attributes;
}

- (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // 1
    NSArray *layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    [layoutAttributes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
     ^(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes,
       NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         [self applySettingsToAttributes:attributes];
     }];
    return layoutAttributes;
}

-(void)applySettingsToAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)attributes {
    // 1
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = attributes.indexPath;
    attributes.zIndex = -indexPath.item;

    // 2
    attributes.frame= CGRectMake([_object.x floatValue], [_object.y floatValue], [_object.width floatValue], [_object.height floatValue]);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve the issue was create a dictionary when the collectionviewcontroller loads with the objects and their indexpaths from the fetchedresultscontroller. This dictionary  is then passed to the UICollectionViewFlowLayout. In the applySettingsToAttributes method in the UICollectionViewFlowLayout i get the object back out of the dictionary and set the attributes frame from the object.

My previous problem was that i was setting the object when the cell was being created, which only worked when i inserted a new object and not when the view was being loaded/refreshed.